# Why does Thread class has static methods when we have currentThread() method?

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, java-threads

`Thread` class has many static methods that are called by class name. Some of them are:
[image]

But yet, we are provided with method `currentThread()` that returns currently executing thread object. Some are:
[image]

Unfortunately, this created confusion in my head. When I think of a method I want, I have no clue whether I would found it as *static* or *instance*. So why did they make such two approaches?

I mean, couldn't they all be grouped in same 'calling'? For example why is `sleep()` *static* and not *instance* method called with `Thread.currentThread().sleep()`? Another weird example is between `interrupted()` and `isInterrupted()` defined in different manner. They do exactly the same thing, just `interrupted()` additionally clears interrupted flag. Has anyone logic answer to this, so I have no struggle where to find each method?

Comment: No, interrupt sets the flag and interrupted gets (and clears) it.

Comment: Oh god yes, I meant interrupted(). I will correct it..

Comment: That doesn't fully correct it. They don't do the same thing. They practically do opposite things. The point is that you can interrupt() any thread but you can only tell whether your own thread is interrupted().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's tricky; the answer is different for each method. Let's go through the ones you named:

### Thread.sleep

Imagine I called: `someOtherThread.sleep(1000L);`. What would this mean? Surely that ought to mean: Sleep that other thread, not my thread. Except that's not something java offers: You can sleep your own thread, but you cannot arbitrarily tell some other thread to freeze like they're doing a mime act, mid execution of some arbitrary command. For example, if that thread is currently blocked on, say, waiting for the OS to deliver some bytes from a file read, that definitely cannot just fall asleep, and there are many, many other scenarios where a thread cannot do that.

Thus, java **does not offer this functionality** - you can't sleep other threads. Only your own. There are two different ways to make this at least somewhat clear in API design:

The first is to have sleep be an instance method (thus, you'd have to write e.g. `Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000L);`), and spec the method that it will guaranteed, always, immediately throw an `IllegalStateException` if you invoke it on any thread except your own. This means a compile/write-time detectable error condition would only be caught at runtime (this is bad; catching a problem earlier is obviously better than catching it later), it makes the code you'd have to write to sleep needlessly longer, and the existence of a sleep method you can invoke on thread instances sure *suggests* that you can sleep other threads. It'd just be crappy API design.

The second is to make sleep static.

Think of it this way: `java.lang.Thread` is a container for two mostly unrelated batches of methods: One is a set of methods you can use on threads (those'd be the instance methods). The other is a bunch of thread and flow related primitives, such as 'sleep', 'yield', and interrupt interaction. They just happen to be shoved into the same class.

### interrupt

This is probably the trickiest. Unlike sleeping, you **can** in fact ask another thread's interrupt flag status.

The reason there are two methods are because of the more or less intended API design of the interrupt system.

The interrupt system is designed as follows:

If you want some thread to stop what it is doing for some unspecified reason (for example, you want it to re-check some condition, or just cease running, or anything else you can think of) then you need a mechanism to signal this. In particular, you'd want such a mechanism to ensure that any interruptable blocking operations, such as `Thread.sleep(100000L)` are interrupted. In other words, you can't just say: Whatever, it's up to the code itself, just, um, make an `AtomicBoolean` and check it a lot.

That's where the 'interrupt' system comes in. The idea is:

1. To interrupt any thread, raise its interrupt flag, with `thatThread.interrupt();`
2. All methods that do interruptable things should check this flag. The procedure is: If it is raised, then [A] clear it, and [B] handle the interruption, doing whatever the programmer intended to happen upon interruption (just stop running, or re-check some condition, re-read some config file, who knows - it's programming, whatever you want it to mean). If you CAN handle the notion of aborting some operation, but you CANNOT handle it, then instead clear that flag and throw InterruptedException, so that the caller can handle it.
3. As a result, any code that knows what 'I was interrupted!' means should BOTH check the flag (especially if that code has an event loop, which most thread-based code does have), AND catch InterruptedException from any method specced to throw it, and react in the exact same way to either catching that exception or having `Thread.interrupted()` return true.

Things go all sorts of wrong if you handle the fact that the interrupt flag is up, but you do NOT lower it. For example, if you abort your CPU-bound bitcoin mining or whatnot and just return back to your caller whilst leaving the flag up, then the next time caller invokes Thread.sleep, thread.sleep will notice the flag is up and IMMEDIATELY exit, not sleeping at all (exit by throwing InterruptedException, to be specific). That isn't intended. Hence why it is important that if you respond to an interrupt, you lower that flag.

So, let's go back to API design. There are two strategies:

### Hypothetical design A

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    mineAnotherBitCoin();
}
Thread.currentThread().clearInterruptFlag();
```

### Design B

```
while (!Thread.checkAndClearInterruptFlag()) {
   mineAnotherBitCoin();
}
```

Note how design B is conceptually a lot shorter, does not have a 'gap' between checking the flag and clearing it, and therefore is fundamentally less error prone. Furthermore, for, well, reasons, it has been decided that raising an interrupt flag is something you can do to other threads (there is no point interrupting yourself, after all), but clearing one is a thing you can only do to your own thread.

B is what java actually has, except the method is somewhat strangely named `interrupted()`, and not `checkAndClearInterruptFlag()`. If you want an explanation of why some methods in java are somewhat suspectly named, it's because java does not like breaking backwards compatibility.

Fundamentally then, while they sound real similar, `isInterrupted()` and `interrupted()` do two very different things.

`isInterrupted()` is to check if some thread has already been interrupted and its response to this interruption is still pending (nothing has yet handled it).

`interrupted()` is something you put in the condition in your while loops that define the core body of your thread implementation (your 'event loop').

*) It doesn't help that the vast majority of examples of how to make threads in java are erroneous in that they don't properly do this. They tend to be `while (true)` or `while (!running) {}` or similar, either ignoring interruptions entirely or with a handrolled interrupt-esque 'running' concept.

### So how do I know where to look?

Simple enough: If it's a thing that conceptually doesn't belong to any particular thread (such as 'how many threads are active right now'), **or** it is a utility concept (such as 'sleep'), **or** it is a thing that from a VM design principle can only be done to your own thread and not to anything else, then it is a static method in Thread.

If it's a thing that does belong to a particular thread AND the VM would let you do it to other threads (such as interrupting it, asking for its name, id, or priority, getting a stack dump, freezing this thread until the other thread completes, or setting its priority), then it's an instance method.

In many ways you can reverse this logic: If you want to do some thread related business, check the Thread class for something that seems to describe what you want. Then check if the method is static or not. If it is static, you don't get to do it to any other thread (such as clearing the interrupt flag, or sleep). If it's instance, you CAN do that to other threads (such as changing its priority level).

Answer (score 2):

Because you can't make another thread sleep that is not the thread you are on. Even when you call `Thread.currentThread().sleep()`, you are calling the static method 'sleep'. If you were to call the `sleep` method on a different `Thread` object, it would still make the current thread sleep.

If you want to make a different thread sleep, you should set a flag that the other thread reads, which causes it to sleep.

Comment: Basically this. The Thread static methods are often for things you can only do on the current thread.